# What would cause Wyse C10LE Thin Clients to suddenly be unable to use dual displays after Windows Updates?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop, monitors

### Problem

- We have a virtual Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 SP1 Remote Desktop server
  with a handful of users logging in from Wyse C10LE thin clients running the
  Linux-based Wyse ThinOS.
- A user turned on automatic updates and the server automatically
  installed updates and rebooted last night
- When the users logged onto this server this morning, their display
  settings were changed and their dual-displays were showing as one
  large screen instead of two separate displays.
- Users cannot change the display settings in a remote session.

### Background Information and Troubleshooting

- Uninstalled the Windows Server 2008 R2 updates that were installed
  last night and rebooted. I left the Security Updates in place, I only removed updates under the "Microsoft Windows" heading in Programs and Features
- Adjusted the Wyse thin client RDP connection display settings
- Tried to adjust Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration settings and Group Policy settings to ensure multiple displays can be used with remote connections.

## Summary

- Windows Updates were installed by mistake
- Remote Desktop connections from our Wyse thin clients won't allow dual displays, shows one very wide display
- All Wyse and Windows display settings I can think of have been checked
- Some of the updates that were installed by mistake have been uninstalled and another reboot has been performed

Comment: This is definitely Windows Update-related. The same thing happened on another one of our Remote Desktop servers. Out of 5 RD servers, only these two have display issues when logging in from the same Wyse thin clients.

Comment: I moved on to the security updates that were installed last night and removed them all. There were almost 20 and each of them required a reboot to remove, so I wasn't able to determine which one was the culprit, but I will be reinstalling all these updates on a test server of similar configuration so I can figure out which update caused it.

Comment: If you or anyone else affected by this issue would like a support case set up with Microsoft, please contact Susan Bradley - see http://blogs.msmvps.com/bradley/2014/10/24/october-patch-status-report-10-days-past-release/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Update [KB2984972](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2984972) - Uninstall this and reboot the host.

We had the identical issue today after automatic updates were applied.

Comment: Thanks very much. You just saved me a lot of time trying to narrow down which of the 60 updates was the culprit.